# Configuring Visual Studio Source Server / Symbol Store against unsupported Vault SCM app

Tags: debugging, symbols, pdb-files, source-server

I am trying to configure our in house development code as a symbol server, with source control file access when debugging in Visual Studio 2008. We can use this on other projects that reference our core set of libraries.

Sadly, we use SourceGear Vault for our SCM system, which is currently unsupported when it comes to indexing our .PDB files with their source control references.

I wouldn't really need direct source control access, I'd be happy with just a network share access but I can't see how to update the references in the PDB files.

I have the symbol server configured and have added what would seem the right references to the original build source code, however, when I debug in Visual Studio and try and step into the code referenced, it does not load the PDBs from the source server and consequently no source code is available.

Also, where Visual Studio can download the core .NET PDB files via the Load Symbols command, I do not have that option when I click the module.

Does anyone have any personal experience of setting this sort of thing up?

Many thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has kind of been resolved [at this other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694665/ms-source-server-source-stream-is-apparently-not-there-when-viewing-with-srctoo).

Source indexing was missing from the overall process so the PDB symbol server should work properly now.